# Reference member to constructor argument pass by value

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is an example code with a reference member to the constructor argument pass by value:

```
struct A
{
    A(std::string name): name_(name){}
    std::string name_;
};

struct B
{
    B(A a): a_(a)
    {
    }
    A& a_;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
    {
        A a("a");
        b.reset(new B(a));
    }
    b->a_.name_ = "b";

    return 0;
}
```

Does `a_` still refer to a existing object in this line `b->a_.name_ = "b"`  ? Is it the similar case as returning a reference to the function local object ?

Comment: No, that is undefined behavior.  `a_` refers to a copy of `a` that is destructed as soon as control leaves the scope of the constructor.  As you said, this is similar to returning a reference to a function-local variable.

Comment: BTW, your dangling reference already starts in B constructor, as you take reference of parameter.

Comment: I have thought that a_ becomes a dangling reference when control leaves the scope of the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a_ still refer to a existing object in this line b->a_.name_ = "b" ?

Nope.
That is an [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In particular, the `B` constructor

```
B(A a): a_(a)
{
}
```

generates a *dangling reference*.

The liveness of the parameter `a` is limited to the scope of the constructor call. Once the constructor ends, the object `a` will be destroyed.
Therefore, the reference you've initialized `a_` is pointing to a destroyed object.

When you try to access it, though:

```
b->a_.name_ = "b";
```

you are actually invoking an undefined behavior because the object does not exist anymore (and that is bad!).

---

> Is it the similar case as returning a reference to the function local object ?

If you return a reference to an object which does not exist anymore and you try to access to it, well... still the same undefined behavior: dangling reference.

---

#### Additional Note

By the construction of your code, the following change is still wrong:

```
B(A& a): a_(a)
    {
    }
```

Note the parameter is now passed-by-reference now.

Indeed, even if you don't take a copy of the object the referenced `A` will be destroyed when you try to access it:

```
{ 
     A a("a");
     b.reset(new B(a));
}  // Here a will be destroyed because out of scope (as automatic variable).
```